# Build C# solution (including UnitTests) in Blend 4 without Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

how can one build a C# solution including the unit tests in Blend 4 without having Visual Studio 2010 installed?

The errors I get are:

```
 The reference could not be resolved. Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
```

and

```
The type and Name space "VisualStudio" is not included in the Namespace "Microsoft" (is an assembly reference missing?)
```

Any way I can get this to work without installing MS VS?

Update: When I manually copy the dll for the Microsoft.VisualStuio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework I still get the second error.

Comment: May I ask, why won't you install VS?

Comment: It's the designers notebook, I didn't want to bloat it and also not buy a license if it could be prevented by installing something free

Answer (score 2):

You have to use another framework for unit tests, such as NUnit. The Visual Studio unit test framework is not installed, as Visual Studio isn't.

http://www.nunit.org/

Comment: Visual Studio Express doesn't contain unit testing so yes, NUnit would be your best bet.

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to install the dlls from VS?